Why does the ECE increase after applying temperature scaling?
I am planning to apply temperature scaling to the output of my model. To determine the optimal temperature, I employed cross-validation and utilized the code available at this link: https://github.com/gpleiss/temperature_scaling However, in some instances, even though the Negative Log Likelihood (NLL) decreases, the Expected Calibration Error (ECE) increases after the application of temperature scaling.
I have tried decreasing the learning rate and increasing the max_iter parameters for the optimizer, yet the issue persists. What could be causing this behavior, and how might I address it?
